# Tengo un problema con una NullPointerException al comparar un String

Tags: java, array, nullpointerexception

Bueno, en este programa la idea es dar de alta un departamento y luego dar de alta un empleado, lo cual te pide un departamento en el que trabaje el empleado.

El problema es que al poner el departamento hice un método para comparar el introducido con uno ya existente y que si existe me regrese un true para completar la creación de dicho empleado pero me da un `NullPointerException` y no se el motivo o razón.

Si no entienden mi petición lo que tengo que hacer es que el vendedor registrado en un `Hashtable` y el departamento en un arreglo de objetos me dejen calcular la comisión del vendedor basado en su importe de ventas, lo que yo quiero es que me deje registrar el vendedor al comparar el departamento ingresado con uno del arreglo ya existente.

Este es mi código:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Principal {

    int op;
    int depaid;
    Departamento depo[] = new Departamento[10];
    Vendedor vn = new Vendedor();
    Scanner nc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Hashtable<Integer, Vendedor> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, Vendedor>();

    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        Principal m = new Principal();
        m.menu();
    }

    public void menu() {
        int op;
        Scanner nc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Que desea hacer? ");
            System.out.println("1-° Dar de alta un vendedor.");
            System.out.println("2-° Asignar el valor de ventas. ");
            System.out.println("3-° Consultar a un empleado.");
            System.out.println("4-° Consultar a todos los vendedores.");
            System.out.println("5-° Dar de alta un departamento.");
            System.out.println("6-° Calcular comsion.");
            System.out.println("7-° Salir.");
            op = nc.nextInt();

            switch (op) {
                case 1:
                    altae();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    asignar();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    buscar();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    imprime();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    altad();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    calculac();
            }
        } while (op != 7);
    }

    public void calculac() {
        String nom2;
        System.out.println("Introuduzca el nombre del empleado");
        String nom = nc.nextLine();
        nom = nom.toUpperCase();
        Enumeration<Vendedor> eht = ht.elements();

        while (eht.hasMoreElements()) {
            Vendedor ven = eht.nextElement();
            nom2 = ven.getNombre();
            if (nom.compareTo(ven.getNombre()) == 0) {
                System.out.println("Salut");
            }
        }
    }

    public void altae() {
        String dep1;

        System.out.println("Introduzca la clave del empleado");
        int cl = nc.nextInt();

        if (ht.containsKey(cl)) {
            System.out.println("La clave ya existe");
        } else {
            nc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del empleado");
            String nom = nc.nextLine();
            if (nom != null) {
                System.out.println("Introduzca el departamento del empleado ");
                String dep = nc.nextLine();
                if (dep != null) {
                    if (BuscaDep(dep)) {
                        System.out.println("Hola");
                        vn = new Vendedor(cl, nom.toUpperCase(), dep.toUpperCase(), 0);
                        System.out.println("Dado de alta exitosamente");
                        ht.put(cl, vn);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("El departamento no puede ser nulo");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("El nombre no puede ser nulo");
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean BuscaDep(String nomD) {
        boolean bandera = false;
        for (int n = 0; n < depo.length; n++) {
            if (depo[n].getNom() != null) {
                if (nomD.compareTo(depo[n].getNom()) == 0) {//No entra en este iff
                    bandera = true;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(bandera);
        return bandera;
    }

    public void altad() {
        String dep;
        int cld;
        double com;
        System.out.println("Introduzca la clave del departamento");
        cld = nc.nextInt();
        nc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del nuevo departamento");
        dep = nc.nextLine();
        if (dep != null) {
            System.out.println("Introduzca el porcentaje de comision en decimal");
            com = nc.nextDouble();
            if (com > 0) {
                depo[depaid] = new Departamento(cld, dep.toUpperCase(), com);
                depaid++;
                System.out.println("Departamento creado exitosamente");
            }
        }
    }

    public void buscar() {
        String nom2;
        System.out.println("Introuduzca el nombre del empleado");
        String nom = nc.nextLine();
        nom = nom.toUpperCase();
        Enumeration<Vendedor> eht = ht.elements();

        while (eht.hasMoreElements()) {
            Vendedor ven = eht.nextElement();
            nom2 = ven.getNombre();
            if (nom.compareTo(ven.getNombre()) == 0) {
                System.out.println("Se encontro: " + ven);
            }
        }
    }

    public void imprime() {
        Enumeration<Integer> rht = ht.keys();
        while (rht.hasMoreElements()) {
            Integer clave = (Integer) rht.nextElement();
            System.out.println(ht.get(clave));
        }
    }

    public void asignar() {
        System.out.println("Introduzca la clave del empleado");
        int cl = nc.nextInt();
        if (ht.containsKey(cl)) {
            Vendedor ven = ht.get(cl);
            System.out.println("Cuanto desea agregar al importe de venta");
            double idv = nc.nextDouble();
            ven.setIdv(idv);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No se encontró");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Vendedor {

    private int clave;
    private String nombre, departamento;
    private double idv;

    public Vendedor() {
    }

    public Vendedor(int clave, String nombre, String departamento, double idv) {
        this.clave = clave;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.departamento = departamento;
        this.idv = idv;
    }

    public Vendedor(int clave, String nombre, String departamento) {
        this.clave = clave;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.departamento = departamento;
    }

    public int getClave() {
        return clave;
    }

    public void setClave(int clave) {
        this.clave = clave;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getDepartamento() {
        return departamento;
    }

    public void setDepartamento(String departamento) {
        this.departamento = departamento;
    }

    public double getIdv() {
        return idv;
    }

    public void setIdv(double idv) {
        this.idv = this.idv + idv;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vendedor [Clave del empleado: " + clave + ", Nombre=" + nombre + ", Departamento=" + departamento + ", Importe de ventas=" + idv
                + "]";
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Departamento {

    private int claved;
    private String nom;
    private double comision;

    public Departamento() {
    }

    public Departamento(int claved, String nom, double comision) {
        this.claved = claved;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.comision = comision;
    }

    public int getClaved() {
        return claved;
    }

    public void setClaved(int claved) {
        this.claved = claved;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public double getComision() {
        return comision;
    }

    public void setComision(double comision) {
        this.comision = comision;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Departamento [Clave de departamento=" + claved + ", Nombre=" + nom + ", Porcentaje de Comision=" + comision + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor, cuando plantees una pregunta coloca la parte del mensaje de error que te da, en el caso de Java son las líneas cercanas a la palabra `Caused by`. Puedes hacerlo cortando y pegando dichas líneas al inicio o al final de tu pregunta, no hace falta hacer otra pregunta, sino editar  la pregunta. Así será más fácil saber dónde está fallando el programa sin tener que leer y analizar todo el código.

Comment: Disculpa, no sera comparar en vez de comprar?

Comment: En vez de: `if(nomD.compareTo(depo[n].getNom())==0) {` yo haría `if (nomD.equals(depo[n].getNom()) {`

Comment: El motivo para un NPE es que se trata de llamar un método a una variable que apunta a `null`. El error en sí normalmente es fácil de encontrar con el StackTrace completo, luego se puede reconstruir porque la variable contiene `null`. Podrías compartir el StackTrace completo?

Answer (score 0):

El problema se encuentra dentro del método `BuscaDep()`, al tratar de obtener los valores del array de objetos departamento, variable `depo`, todos los elementos tienen valor null, es por eso que obtienes NullPointerException.

```
 public boolean BuscaDep(String nomD) {
        boolean bandera = false;
        for (int n = 0; n < depo.length; n++) {
            if (depo[n].getNom() != null) {  //*** Los elementos dentro del array tienen valor null.
                if (nomD.compareTo(depo[n].getNom()) == 0) {//No entra en este iff
                    bandera = true;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(bandera);
        return bandera;
    }
```

Para evitar que busque elementos `Departamento` con valor null, evita el llamando del metodo `BuscaDep(dep)` ya que en ese punto no se ha creado ningun departamento, cuando das de alta un vendedor comenta las siguientes lineas:

```
   public void altae() {

     ...
     ...
                System.out.println("Introduzca el departamento del empleado ");
                String dep = nc.nextLine();
                if (dep != null) {
                    //if (BuscaDep(dep)) {
                        System.out.println("Hola");
                        vn = new Vendedor(cl, nom.toUpperCase(), dep.toUpperCase(), 0);
                        System.out.println("Dado de alta exitosamente");
                        ht.put(cl, vn);
                    //}
                } else {
                    System.out.println("El departamento no puede ser nulo");
         ...
         ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es un poco de lo que alcancé a arreglar. eliminé el Hashtable. Ordené un poco las variable, pero aun hay algunos errores :P (quizá los corrija)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Principal {

    static final String MSG_INGRESE_COMISION_DEPARTAMENTO = "Introduzca el porcentaje de comision en decimal";
    static final String MSG_DEPARTAMENTO_CREADO = "Departamento creado exitosamente";
    static final String MSG_INGRESE_NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO = "Introduzca el nombre del departamento";
    static final String MSG_INGRESE_CLAVE_DEPARTAMENTO = "Introduzca la clave del departamento";
    static final String MSG_INGRESE_NOMBRE_EMPLEADO = "Introuduzca el nombre del empleado";
    static final String MSG_INGRESE_CLAVE_EMPLEADO = "Introduzca la clave del empleado";
    static final String MSG_OPCION_INVALIDA = "Ingese una opcion válida.";
    static final String MSG_OPCIONES_MENU = "Que desea hacer?\n1-° Dar de alta un vendedor.\n"
            + "2-° Asignar el valor de ventas.\n3-° Consultar a un empleado.\n4-° Consultar a "
            + "todos los vendedores.\n5-° Dar de alta un departamento.\n6-° Calcular comsion.\n"
            + "7-° Salir.";

    ArrayList<Departamento> departamentos = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Vendedor> vendedores = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        Principal m = new Principal();
        m.ImprimirMenu();
    }

    public void ImprimirMenu() {
        int opcion;

        do {
            System.out.println(MSG_OPCIONES_MENU);

            try {
                opcion = scan.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                opcion = -1;
            }
            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    crearVendedor();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    asignarVentas();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    buscarEmpleado();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    imprimeVendedores();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    crearDepartemento();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    calculaComision();
                default:
                    System.out.println(MSG_OPCION_INVALIDA);
            }
        } while (opcion > 0 || opcion < 8);
    }

    public void calculaComision() {

    }

    public void crearVendedor() {
        int dep, claveVendedor;
        String nombreVendedor = null;

        do {
            System.out.println(MSG_INGRESE_CLAVE_EMPLEADO);
            try {
                claveVendedor = scan.nextInt();
                if (indiceVendedor(claveVendedor) != -1) {
                    System.out.println("La clave ya existe");
                    claveVendedor = -1;
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                claveVendedor = -1;
            }
        } while (claveVendedor <= 0);

        do {
            System.out.println(MSG_INGRESE_NOMBRE_EMPLEADO);
            nombreVendedor = scan.nextLine();
        } while (nombreVendedor == null || nombreVendedor.trim().length() <= 0);

        do {
            System.out.println("Introduzca el departamento del empleado ");
            dep = scan.nextInt();

        } while (dep < 0);

        vendedores.add(new Vendedor(claveVendedor, nombreVendedor.toUpperCase(), dep, 0));
        System.out.println("Dado de alta exitosamente");
    }

    public boolean existeDepartamento(int clave) {
        for (Departamento dept : departamentos) {
            if (clave == dept.getClave()) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void crearDepartemento() {
        int claveDept;
        double comisionDept;
        String nombreDept = null;

        do {
            System.out.println(MSG_INGRESE_CLAVE_DEPARTAMENTO);
            try {
                claveDept = scan.nextInt();

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                claveDept = -1;
            }
        } while (claveDept > 0);

        do {
            System.out.println(MSG_INGRESE_NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO);
            nombreDept = scan.nextLine();
        } while (nombreDept != null && nombreDept.trim().length() > 0);

        do {
            System.out.println(MSG_INGRESE_COMISION_DEPARTAMENTO);
            try {
                comisionDept = scan.nextDouble();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                comisionDept = -1;
            }
        } while (comisionDept > 0);

        departamentos.add(new Departamento(claveDept, nombreDept.toUpperCase(), comisionDept));
        System.out.println(MSG_DEPARTAMENTO_CREADO);
    }

    public void buscarEmpleado() {
        String nombreVendedor;
        System.out.println(MSG_INGRESE_NOMBRE_EMPLEADO);

        do {
            System.out.println(MSG_INGRESE_NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO);
            nombreVendedor = scan.nextLine();
        } while (nombreVendedor != null && nombreVendedor.trim().length() > 0);

        int indice = indiceVendedor(nombreVendedor);

        if (indice >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Se encontró " + vendedores.get(indice));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No se encontró");
        }
    }

    public int indiceVendedor(String nombre) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vendedores.size(); i++) {
            if (nombre.equals(vendedores.get(i).getNombre())) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public int indiceVendedor(int clave) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vendedores.size(); i++) {
            if (clave == vendedores.get(i).getClave()) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public void imprimeVendedores() {
        for (Vendedor vend : vendedores) {
            System.out.println(vend);
        }
    }

    public void asignarVentas() {

    }
}
```